# cartesian multiplication when having three array

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am a beginner in programming.  I have three arrays having elements 2, 3 , 4 respectively. How do I get the cartesian product like this?

`A[1]B[1]C[1] , A[1]B[2]C[1] , A[1]B[1]C[2],` and so on

```
for(a=0; a<=n; a++)
{
  for(b=0;a<=n; b++)
  {
    for(c=0;c<=n; c++)
    {
      j[][][]=A[n]B[n]C[n]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, because this question wasn't closed yet, I hope it is okay to give some pointers:

1. only start class names with capital letters
2. you get the size of an array `arr` with `arr.length`
3. you loop through the array indexes with `for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` so that it still works if the arrays have different sizes (and not all size n)
4. there is no point of using `ArrayList` here (the question is tagged like that), you know the result size, array will be faster, if the input are the 3 array `a`, `b` and `c` then you declare the return value `ret` like `int[][][] ret = new int[a.length][b.length][c.length]`
5. put everything in a method, e.g. `public int[][][] cartesianProduct(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c)`
6. the assignment inside the 3 loops would be `ret[i][j][k] = a[i] * b[j] * c[k]` with arrays `a`, `b`, `c`, and counters `i`, `j`, `k`.